# How do I use a Chai plugin like chai-date-string with Karma/Mocha/Chai?

Tags: unit-testing, karma-runner, chai

Should be able to use any Chai plugin with unit testing with Karma/Mocha and Chai, or does it need to be converted into a special karma compatible plugin?

I'd like to use [chai-date-string](http://chaijs.com/plugins/chai-date-string/) to do something like `expect(requestBody.time).to.be.a.dateString();`, but didn't have any luck just installing them as an NPM module and requiring them in my test file.

Then I came across [karma-chai-plugins](https://www.npmjs.com/package/karma-chai-plugins), which I thought was designed to use other chai plugins (even beyond the few that it comes bundled with), but adding that as an NPM module, and then adding the Chai plugin name to the frameworks list, but this didn't work.

My `karma.conf.js`:

```
module.exports = function(config) {
  config.set({
    basePath: '',
    frameworks: ['mocha', 'chai', 'chai-date-string', 'sinon-chai', 'browserify'],
    client: { chai: { includeStack: true } },
    files: [ 'playmob.js', 'test/**/*_test.js' ],
    preprocessors: {
      'test/**/*.js': [ 'browserify' ]
    },
    browserify: {
      debug: true,
    },
    exclude: [ ],
    reporters: ['mocha', 'beep'],
    mochaReporter: { ignoreSkipped: true },
    port: 9876,
    colors: true,
    logLevel: config.LOG_INFO,
    autoWatch: true,
    browsers: ['ChromeHeadless'],
    singleRun: false,
    concurrency: Infinity
  })
}
```

Versions in `package.json` (I had to explicitly install a newer version of `chai-as-promised` to get around a dependency problem):

```
  "devDependencies": {
    "browserify": "^14.4.0",
    "chai": "^4.1.2",
    "chai-as-promised": "^7.1.1",
    "chai-date-string": "^0.1.0",
    "karma": "^1.7.1",
    "karma-beep-reporter": "^0.1.4",
    "karma-browserify": "^5.1.1",
    "karma-chai-plugins": "^0.9.0",
    "karma-chrome-launcher": "^2.2.0",
    "karma-cli": "^1.0.1",
    "karma-mocha": "^1.3.0",
    "karma-mocha-reporter": "^2.2.4",
    "karma-sinon-chai": "^1.3.2",
    "mocha": "^3.5.3",
    "sinon": "^2.4.1",
    "sinon-chai": "^2.14.0",
    "uglifyjs": "^2.4.11",
    "url": "^0.11.0",
    "watchify": "^3.9.0"
  }
```

Results in the following error:

```
> playmobjs@0.2.0 test /Users/jschuur/Code/Playmob/js_api_lib
> karma start

/Users/jschuur/Code/Playmob/js_api_lib/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:9
      throw error('No provider for "' + name + '"!');
      ^

Error: No provider for "framework:chai-date-string"! (Resolving: framework:chai-date-string)
    at error (/Users/jschuur/Code/Playmob/js_api_lib/node_modules/di/lib/injector.js:22:12)
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

When I look at the code of `karma-chai-plugins` I see a series of [hardcoded plugin names](https://github.com/princed/karma-chai-plugins/blob/d97b7c928aaa3bee5f09464d3a756dbea6c4c2dc/index.js#L55). It seems to me that `karma-chai-plugins` recognizes only those Chai plugins that are hardcoded in its source. So I don't think you can use it for `chai-date-string`.

Moreover, `chai-date-string` is not distributed in a format that is readily loadable in a browser. You could use Browserify or Webpack to convert it to a file that exports something like `chaiDateString` into the global space. Then you'd have to:

1. Include in `files` your converted `chai-date-string` script.
2. Add another script in `files` that invokes `chai.use(chaiDateString)`. The [example code](https://github.com/googoid/chai-date-string) shown in the repo omits the call to `chai.use`, but it cannot be omitted.

Comment: My setup already uses browserify, and in fact, I use the `url` module in another test, without having set that up somewhere in `karma.conf.js`, so I wasn't sure much more setup would be needed.

I did go through your recommendations and tried adding `chai.use(chaiDateString);` to the top of my playmob_test.js file, as well as a few variants of including `node_modules/chai-date-string/index.js` in my `files` block, but no luck. I still get the same error.

Comment: If you are getting the *same* error that would be because you are still using `chai-date-string` in your `frameworks` setting. You must remove it from there. (That was implied by my first paragraph because the only thing that *would* allow it to be in `frameworks` is `karma-chai-plugins` but you cannot use it.) And yes, I see you are using browserify. I guess you could use the configuration you already have *if* you use `var chaiDateString = require("chai-date-string")` in your test files and put `chai.use(chaiDateString)` in each test file.

Comment: However, if you want `chai-date-string` to be setup once and for all without having to `require` it in all test files you cannot rely on the Browserify configuration you have in your `karma.conf.js`. You'd need to treat `chai-date-string` separately from your test files. I've not used Browserify in Karma so I don't know whether you can perform the requisite configuration for this inside `karma.conf.js`.

Comment: I just experimented some more after my comment and discovered what you said: As long as I added `chai.use(chaiDateString)`, it'll work just fine, without  any special references in `karma.conf.js`. Turns out it was easier than I thought! Thanks for nudging me over the line. My understanding is at some point all modules that start with `karma-` get loaded automatically, so I don't even need to have it in the `frameworks` block either. Problem solved!

Comment: One final clarification: Turns out you don't need `karma-chai-plugins` at all, if you're just using a chai plugin this way.